# TabLayoutPanel not showing widgets only Tab items are visible

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Simple example of TabLayoutPanel not showing container widgets only Tab items are visible.
Something going wrong is it works for IE8

```
public class DemoGWT implements EntryPoint {
    RootPanel rp = RootPanel.get();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        TabLayoutPanel panel = new TabLayoutPanel(25, Unit.PX);
        Label a = new Label("One Container");
        panel.add(a, "One Hdr");
        panel.add(new Label("Two Container"), "Two Hdr");
        panel.add(new Label("Three Container"), "Three Hdr");
        panel.add(new Label("Four Container"), "Four Hdr");
        panel.add(new Label("Five Container"), "Five Hdr");
        panel.add(new Label("Six Container"), "Six Hdr");

        rp.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: panel.setPixelSize(450, 100); with this it is working fine, before that the code doesn't that statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix up **Layout panels** and **panels**. When you use layout panels such as TabLayoutPanel, Make sure its parent and their parent upto RootPanel are layout panels. Use **RootLayoutPanel** instead of **RootPanel**. TabLayoutPanel will not display data unless you mention its absolute height. (Note 100% or any other % won't work). It has to be absolute.

Change the `RootPanel` to `RootLayoutPanel` and use `setHeight(height)` API of your `TabLayoutPanel`. **Don't mention height in %age.**

Comment: But the TabPanel is deprciated

Comment: Yes TabPanel is deprecated and should be avoided. Hence use "RootLayoutPanel" with "TabLayoutPanel".

Comment: when did I say to use tabpanel... I am saying you to use tablayoutpanel and rootlayoutpanel

Comment: Okay none of its parent panel is layout panel, i initially used DecoratedTabPanel with rounded corner images, i have Width usage concerns, so to utilize width more i put my head into TabLayoutPanel, i got this issue, after placing setPixelSize its working in FF and chrome but not in IE8

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with ie8 with tab client areas not being displayed.

We had created ui XML template panel.
Our setup was to display a TabLayoutPanel within a tab of another
TabLayoutPanel. The first TabLayoutPanel was entirely visible, the child
TabLayoutPanel was invisible but not 'hidden'.

BTW this problem didn't exhibit itself under Firefox!!!!!

Making all panels children of ResizeComposite and ultimately children of root layout panel
made no difference. However I kept that mod as it seemed to be the correct GWT way of coding layout
panels.

The problems solution as it turned out was quite surprising and unexpected.

I had specified sizes of composite panels in EM units. When I switched the child
TabLayoutPanel to PX units and it's tab children panels to PX units everything displayed OK.