# GWT TabPanel in firefox , IE8 & 9

Tags: gwt

I have an application developed in IE7 and it works fine, but when we try to run it in Firefox, ie8 & 9 the widgets in tabPanel does not load/show, everything works fine thou except only not showing the widgets in the tabpanel.

Comment: Please add more details and code snippets to the query. Also update whether the below mention solution worked and what else did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of the tab panel and You should maintain consisting in Layouts heirarchy. Either use Lay out panels everywhere or use just panels.

> I think the problem is you used both Panels and Layout Panles.

For more info refer below link -

[TabLayoutPanel not showing widgets only Tab items are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738904/tablayoutpanel-not-showing-widgets-only-tab-items-are-visible/13739312#13739312)